# Updating an intrinsic rotation with an extrinsic rotation

Tags: javascript, vector, rotation

I am trying to model a Rubik's Cube for a personal project, using [Zdog](https://zzz.dog/) for lightweight 3d graphics. Zdog uses a `{x,y,z}` vector to represent rotation - I believe this is essentially a [Tait-Bryan angle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_angles#Tait%E2%80%93Bryan_angles).

[image]

To animate a rotation of the top, right, front, etc side, I attach the 9 blocks to an [anchor](https://zzz.dog/modeling#concepts-anchors) in the center of the cube and rotate it 90 degrees in the desired direction. This works great, but when the animation is done I need to "save" the translation and rotation on the 9 blocks. Translation is relatively simple, but I'm stuck on rotation. I basically need a function like this:

```
function updateRotation(xyz, axis, angle) {
  // xyz is a {x,y,z} vector
  // axis is "x", "y", or "z"
  // rotation is the angle of rotation in radians
}
```

that would apply the `axis`/`angle` rotation in *world coordinates* to the `xyz` vector in *object* coordinates. Originally I just had `xyz[axis] += angle`, but this only works when no other axis has any rotation. I then thought I could use a lookup table, and I think that's possible as I only use quarter turns, but constructing the table turns out to be harder than I thought.

I am starting to suspect I need to translate the `xyz` vector to some other representation (matrix? quaternion?) and apply the rotation there, but I'm not sure where to start. The frustrating thing is that my blocks are in the right position at the end of the animation - I'm just not sure how to apply the parent transform so that I can detach them from the parent without losing the rotation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell, this can't be done with Euler angles alone (at least not in any easy way). My solution was to convert to quaternions, rotate, then convert back to Euler:

```js
function updateRotation(obj, axis, rotation) {
  const {x, y, z} = obj.rotate;
  
  const q = new Quaternion()
    .rotateZ(z)
    .rotateY(y)
    .rotateX(x);
  
  const q2 = new Quaternion();
  if (axis === 'x') {
    q2.rotateX(rotation);
  } else if (axis === 'y') {
    q2.rotateY(rotation);
  } else if (axis === 'z') {
    q2.rotateZ(rotation);
  }
  
  q.multiply(q2, null);

  const e = new Euler().fromQuaternion(q);
  
  obj.rotate.x = e.x;
  obj.rotate.y = e.y;
  obj.rotate.z = e.z;
  obj.normalizeRotate();
}
```

This uses the `Euler` and `Quaternion` classes from [math.gl](https://github.com/uber-web/math.gl).

(It turned out Zdog actually uses `ZYX` Euler angles as far as I could tell, hence the order of rotations when creating the first quaternion.)